# TortoiseHG -Stop using machine name and current user when pushing to repo

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I'm pretty new to HG, forgive me if I use the wrong terminology here, but is it possible to change TortoiseHG to stop pushing the currently logged-in user and machine 
name when doing a push?

My assumption is that it is using my locally cloned repository to say where the change is coming from.  I'd like to "alias" that or use something more meaningful to me.  For example, when I do a push the history shows that the push came from `adam@mypc` but I would prefer it to just say something like `adam`.

My reasoning is that I have several PCs where I may check in code from, and I would prefer it if all of my checkin's could be aliased the same instead of being separated by machine name.

Thoughts/suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't [set your username](http://hgtip.com/tips/beginner/2009-09-28-set-your-username/).

Comment: Ah ha.  I knew it would be simple.  Is it possible to change the history in the repo to update previous commits to that user name?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm fairly new to Hg myself. I think that if you want to be able to change the past, you need to use git.

Comment: Mercurial and git have similar ways to edit history.  Both are a Bad Idea if you have shared that history (someone has pulled from you or you have pushed somewhere).  If you haven't then look at Mercurial Queues or the histedit extension.